# Can not inspect S4 object after modification

Tags: r, r-s4

I am having problems with my S4 object `res`after I appended a list of values to it. The object was created with the DESeq2 package. The object was created via:

```
dds <- DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData = count.matrix,
                              colData = coldata,
                              design = ~ Condition)
dds <- DESeq(dds, test = "Wald")
res <- results(dds)
```

I did the following:

```
x <- qvalue(res@listData[["pvalue"]])    #calc qvalues based on pvalues from S4 object 'res'
res@listData[["qval"]] <- x[["qvalues"]] #append qvalues from x to 'res' as new col named "qval"
```

Now when I try to inspect the object with `head()` I get the following error:

```
> head(res)
Error in `rownames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = names(x)) : 
  invalid rownames length
```

The funny thing is that with `View()`I can inspect the S4 object in RStudio and I can see that everything went fine, adding the qvalues. Does anyone know why this happens? Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: Hi can provide some background on where (which package) this S4 object is from or if you created it, how?

Comment: Hi updated the original post. I used the DESeq2 package for that.

Comment: Do you know for sure that `head` is supposed to work on objects of this class?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I ended up simply doing `head(as.data.frame(res))` which worked.  @JDL: Yes before I added the qvalues `head` worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you to get the qvalues.. you can do this first:

```
library(qvalue)
library(DESeq2)

dds = makeExampleDESeqDataSet()
dds = DESeq(dds)
res = results(dds)
res$qvalue = qvalue(res$pvalue)$qvalue
```

I will follow up with why there is an error.. you need to look into how it is constructed.